# Elasticsearch terms filter, but for a prefix

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that I want to filter for multiple values. I'm currently doing this with a `terms` filter:

```
"filter" : {
            "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}
        }
```

But I want the filter to match on prefixes as well as whole terms, something like this (`prefixes` is just me pseudocoding what I want):

```
 "filter" : {
            "prefixes" : { "user" : ["kim", "elast"]}
        }
```

Or do I have to resort to multiple `or` filters?

```
"filter" : {
            "or" : {
                "filters" : [
                    {
                        "prefix" : { "user" : "kim" }
                    },
                    {
                        "prefix" : { "user" : "elast" }
                    }
                ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ES` does not have anything like `prefixes` but

1) you could use [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) rather than writing multiple `or filters`

You could write your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "users",
      "query": "kim* OR elas*"
    }
  }
}
```

There is one problem though, if your `user` field is mapped as `not_analyzed` then it wont find *Kimchy* , *Elasticsearch* as by default `lowercase_expanded_terms` is true and it will lowercase all your prefixes.

For this to work 100%, I would recommend using [keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html?q=keyword) with [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html?q=lowerc) so that we can make case insensitive search, after that above query will give you desired result. You could add more prefix with `OR`

2) Another approach could be with `keyword tokenizer` mixed with `lowercase` and [`edgengram token filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html). Lets say you use `min_gram : 2` and `max_gram : 7` then you could use `terms` query itself act like multiple prefix query like this

```
"filter": {
    "terms": {
        "user": ["kim", "elast"]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second approach is more resonable.. as in the first approach you have used regex, which tends to go a little slow, more over the query_String is more vulnerable to syntax error..

Comment: @AnirudhModi prefix search is done the same way internally by ES I think, also query_string will be converted to bool internally. I agree that second approach will be faster.

Comment: prefix search works differently.. it seems to do the type while searching, but it has got max_expansion which makes it pretty strictful, as in you wont get desired result...Its best to use edge ngram